# Can't get MAILFROM to work in crontab on Ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: cron

Is MAILFROM supported in crontab in Ubuntu server 12.04?  Cron job errors are sent via exim ok, but the sender, root@localhost, is not acceptable.  MAILFROM in crontab works fine on my Fedora Core 15 server.

Answer (score 3):

The version of cron shipped with Ubuntu up to saucy (a patched Vixie cron 3) does not support the MAILFROM env var.

Fedora uses cronie (https://fedorahosted.org/cronie/), a Vixie cron 4 fork with some enhancements.

Vixie cron 4.1 aka ISC cron also supports this var.

Comment: `Installed: 3.0pl1-128.1ubuntu1` doesn't support =\